# How to get Python3 to find installed module?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, centos

I'm attempting to install `xlsxwriter` on CentOS centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

when I install `xlsxwriter`:

```
703404669@bioitutil2:~$ sudo pip3 install xlsxwriter
Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (1.2.6)
```

and when I attempt to load the module, I get a contradictory message:

```
703404669@bioitutil2:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlsxwriter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

I've also tried `pip3.6`, but get more errors:

```
703404669@bioitutil2:~$ sudo pip3.6 install xlsxwriter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/pip3.6", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can I get python3 to find `xlsxwriter`?

Comment: There are two different questions. Please ask them separately.

Comment: My only question is how to get python3 to find the installed module.  What other question do you see? thanks for helping me to make this more clear

Comment: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` is a separate error. Search it, there're many answers at SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip3 install xlsxwriter
```

gives you

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (1.2.6)
```

so it is installed for `python3.4`, but `python3` calls `Python 3.6.8`, so two different python versions that have their seperate `site-package` directory.

You can avoid this problem by doing `python3 -m pip install`, which should

1. Make sure that you are installing exactly for the python version you are intending to use
2. Avoid the `'module' object is not callable` error

**Note**

I don't know how you ended up having two python versions, but it might be worth to check if you can uninstall one of them and then use a virtual environment or similar to manage multiple python versions on your system

Comment: This computer has a lot of users, each with their own purposes in mind, which has led to many different python versions on this system.  My supervisor gets very frustrated with python, and has some colorful metaphors for it that aren't appropriate to post here in a family-friendly environment.

Comment: Ah okay, you could consider just downloading miniconda, isntall it in **your** home directory and then don't care any more what any other users are doing with their python versions, you will only have one that is only to yourself